# Problem with woocommerce checkout and Paypal - buy button does not redirect to paypal as it doesnt change the form action

Tags: woocommerce, paypal

I am using paypal plus with woocommerce as you can see here: https://www.pro-hypnose.de

The paypal display is working so far. But when I click the buy button (here "jetzt kaufen" it does not redirect to paypal. It leads to a summary of the products without adress information. An email is being sent with a buy now link.

The form action remains still as

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="https://www.pro-hypnose.de/checkout/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The console says the following: Content Security Policy: Die Einstellungen der Seite haben das Laden einer Ressource auf inline blockiert ("script-src"). in English: the configuration has blocked a resource
Shouldn't it changes to a paypal destination? What can be the reason for it? I also checked if there is a double form tag. It isn't.

Comment: Change the content security policy HTTP header of your site/server to allow execution of that script on that page

Comment: What I tried for wordpress is this in the function.php                                 header('Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=15768000');

header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');

header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');

header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: data: *.pro-hypnose.de"); It doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: It seems to be that script: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js but how can I force to allow it? Any help appreciatet

Comment: Change the content security policy header to allow www.paypalobjects.com

Comment: If https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js is blocked, shoudn't I am being unable to view the source? If I click on it, the script show up

Comment: That's not how it works

Comment: But how? Any solution appreciatet

Comment: Above you show a Content-Security-Policy that does not include the domain you are attempting to load a script from. The script will not load on that page, it is forbidden by the policy. You must change the header of the page being served.